# Eclipse Editor plug-in key binding not shown in menu for command

Tags: eclipse-plugin, contextmenu, key-bindings

I have a key binding that triggers a command in my custom Eclipse editor plug-in:

```
  <key
        commandId="my.plugin.ui.MyCommand"
        contextId="my.plugin.ui.mycontext"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="M1+M2+O">
  </key>
```

I am using a newly defined context `mycontext` to be able to overwrite the already existing key binding for organizing imports. `mycontext` is a child context of `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window`.

When creating a menu entry for this command, the keyboard shortcut is not shown next to the label because the context for the binding is not `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window` but its child.

The desired presentation would look like that of the default binding when right-clicking `.java` files:

**Organize Imports** __*_*__*_*__*_*___  **Ctrl+Shift+O**

Is there a way to show the bindings for custom contexts?

Comment: The key binding will only be shown (and will only be used) when your context is actually active.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to activate the context in the view's create part control method.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IContextService.class).activateContext("custom.context.id");
        }
    });
```